# When do you say that you are perfect in OOP?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, object, methods

It has been a year I am programming using PHP. I use Procedural programming method most of the time. I found using Procedural programming quick and easy to implement.

I started using php oop after about 6 months. I like it because I have saved a lot of code re-writing but i found it challenging and time consuming. I am still using more variables in my classes rather than arrays. I have seen some really good examples of OOP and they are using arrays a lot.

What can I do to achieve perfection or become better? When do you say you are perfect in OOP? I have started thinking that my learning capability is slowing down a lot. That's because I have already learnt how to get the task done. what php methods I have to use for example, I can go to php.net and grab the method and finish my task. So i don't know what else I can take out of php.

I have also worked with OOP frameworks for a while and seen that I can use their methods, I  can understand most of their code used in methods. I can call methods according to needs. But problem is I myself can't write OO code like they do, in my own classes.

If you say review your code and try to shorten it after then I might run of time or my manager would think why am I taking so long or something else that's the reason I use procedural method most of the time because that's easy and quick. Moreover, I think because my manager just need work so why care about coding conventions.

I hope most of you experienced programmer might have been through this situation. Please share any thoughts that could help me and other new programmers out there. Thanks

Comment: Short answer? One is NEVER perfect in anything. Really good, yes. But never perfect. There's always a concept that doesn't come to mind, or a problem we can't solve 'easily'. That's why SO was invented. To ask questions and get the opinions and views of others. Regarding the 'getting better'...practice helps heaps. After a while, you'll get the hang of it and write more efficient classes each time.

Comment: It's all about change and separating what changes from what stays the same. I remember reading that somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "perfect" is subjective, here's a few things you can do to get close:

- Read books.  Don't read PHP or OOP specific books.  Rather, read books about programming techniques that won't become obsolete.  My personal favorite is Code Complete 2
- Read code.  Of all the ways one can learn more, reading the code of someone smarter/better than you is the most effective, specifically when you're trying to learn more about a specific language.
- Code.  A lot.  In coding, as with most creative endeavors, quantity matters more than quality, because if you create a lot, you'll end up learning a lot, and you will get better.
- Don't be afraid to try new things.  The only way to avoid becoming stagnant in your programming is to tackle bigger projects than you think you can handle.

And don't forget, Jeff Atwood says you [shouldn't program all the time.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/01/how-to-become-a-better-programmer-by-not-programming.html)

Comment: I agree with SomeKittens, but I'll add, try breaking out of php. I feel my biggest growth comes when I'm using multiple languages. For example, my university has me learn c++ and because if the principles learned, I've become loads better at javascript. Maybe set one day a week to learning and trying new things?

Comment: @film42 good point, I added that to my post

Comment: When I think up and tackle projects that I can't handle I feel like I don't grow as I can never get a foothold in anything.